# How can I get 10 products from each category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

A product has one or many categories. `Categories` is defined as a has many through model.

So for example:

- Whole milk can belong to the `Dairy` aisle
- Organic whole milk can belong to the `Organic` aisle
- Soy milk can belong to the `Dairy` and `Organic` aisle

How can I get 10 products grouped by each category?

So given the two categories mentioned above. I'd like 10 products from the `Dairy` aisle, and 10 products from the `Organic` aisle.

My model definitions:

```
# Columns: id, name, description, etc
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :aisles, through: :categories, dependent: :destroy
end

# Columns: id, product_id, aisle_id
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :aisle
end

# Columns: id, name, description, etc
class Aisle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :categories, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Aisle.all.map { |a| a.products.limit(10).order('rand()') }
```